# Why is my leaf changing light green on one side?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, nutrients

I have several strains that I am watering with the same nutrients but this one is showing this light green discoloration on half of the leaf. None of the other plants are showing this. All conditions are the same.  Does anyone know what causes this?

Edit: This is an indoor plant. I found it in my basement. It is growing in coco, a 65%/35% coco perlite mix. Good quality coco. We can call it a "tomato plant".

[image: Discoloration of leaf color]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please mention the plant's name in the title and in the text of your question. This will help others in finding the your question in the future - if they have the same problem.

Comment: growing outdoors or indoors? soil less mix or soil type?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we [do not currently allow](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-questions-about-a-marijuana-garden-allowed) questions about *Cannabis*.

Comment: @J.Musser - really? Even now that some States in America have had a change in law and legalised cannabis? Or is that just using it rather than growing it?

Comment: @Bamboo: That is  what the linked  meta question is about. This is a community based site. A member of the community asked the question, and the answeer 'no' got 20 votes from the community. To change this currrent rule, you can add a 'yes' answer and if the community wants it that way, your answer will rise in votes above the other answer, and we will use the higher voted answer to determine our scope. Haha oversimplified that, didn't I...

Comment: @J.Musser - not simple enough, I don't know where to find this No vote to vote yes instead... but on the other hand, I don't want to be dishing out advice regarding growing an illegal crop in public, there's plenty enough on the web already for those that want to know....so I'm still wondering whether people who live in States where this is legal are allowed to grow it, or just buy and use it, any idea?

Comment: @Bamboo, The question was, whether or not to allow these questions, and only one answer, no, got put up. In order to have a 'yes' option, someone will have to add that as an answer... As for the legality of growing it in legalized states, I'm afraid I'm not an expert there, but I can probably look that up for you.

Comment: I'd like to know, if you get time to look it up please - but of course, currently, I don't know where the asker of this particular question is anyway, but it'd be something I'd ask in future if ever there was a Yes vote to answering similar questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29292/discussion-between-j-musser-and-bamboo).

Answer (score 1):

If it resembles anything at all, its possibly sulphur shortage. If you look closely, there is evidence of other, faint discoloration on other leaflets in that leaf, presenting mostly as lighter green parts, as opposed to the distinct yellowing. It might also be a viral infection, hard to say. The first link below is a diagnostic site for hemp plant nutritional problems, but doesn't cover viral infection, the second link is to a site showing a plant infected with Tobacco Mosaic Virus and what to do about it... it doesn't exactly look like TMV currently though.

http://www.thenug.com/galleries/diagnose-your-sick-marijuana-plants

http://bigbudsmag.com/dealing-with-tobacco-mosaic-virus-tmv-br-in-your-marijuana-plants/

You haven't said whether this crop is indoor or outdoor, hydroponic or not, but both links might be of use anyway.

Comment: Nice link, I like the first one. Ill check out the ratios of the element in my nutrients.

Comment: Bamboo: Please see my comment on the question.